# Multiple ClientBootstrap issue

Tags: websocket, netty

I'm coding a tool for load testing of a websocket server. I need create a lot(tens of thousands) of client connections to the server.

So I have a some Client class. Inside this class I create new versions of:

1. ChannelPipelineFactory(with my handlers and the webscoket client handshaker)
2. ClientBootstrap

In the run() method I have the following code:

```
public void run() {
    clientBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(clientChannelPipelineFactory);

    ChannelFuture future = clientBootstrap.connect(
        new InetSocketAddress(
            clientConfiguration.getHost(),
            clientConfiguration.getPort()
        )
    );

    try {
        future.awaitUninterruptibly().rethrowIfFailed();

        WebSocketClientHandshaker handshaker = clientChannelPipelineFactory.getHandshaker();

        channel = future.getChannel();
        handshaker.handshake(channel).awaitUninterruptibly().rethrowIfFailed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error in the client channel", e);
        stop();
    }
}
```

The channel that is returned by ChannelFuture is saved as field in the Client.

Then I do my work and trying to close all opened channles. The stop() method:

```
public void stop() {
    log.debug(String.format("Close channel for client(%s)", id));
    if (channel != null) {
        if (channel.isWritable()) {
            log.debug(String.format("Channel for client(%s) is writable", id));
            ChannelFuture writeFuture = channel.write(new CloseWebSocketFrame());
            writeFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }

    clientBootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
}
```

But, when the stop() is called on any clients it closes all channels!?

p.s.
Code that closes all channels(single threaded):

```
for (FSBBridgeServerClient client : clients) {
        for (FSBBridgeServerClient subClient : clients) {
            log.debug("c:" + subClient.getChannel());
            log.debug("c:" + subClient.getChannel().isOpen());
        }
        client.stop();
}
```

Some debug log:

```
2012-04-04 17:19:29,441 DEBUG [main] ClientApp - c:[id: 0x2344b18f, /127.0.0.1:38366 => localhost/127.0.0.1:5544]
2012-04-04 17:19:29,441 DEBUG [main] ClientApp - c:true
2012-04-04 17:19:29,442 DEBUG [main] ClientApp - c:[id: 0x01c20eb7, /127.0.0.1:38367 => localhost/127.0.0.1:5544]
2012-04-04 17:19:29,442 DEBUG [main] ClientApp - c:true


2012-04-04 17:19:34,414 DEBUG [main] ClientApp - c:[id: 0x2344b18f, /127.0.0.1:38366 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:5544]
2012-04-04 17:19:34,414 DEBUG [main] ClientApp - c:false
2012-04-04 17:19:34,414 DEBUG [main] ClientApp - c:[id: 0x01c20eb7, /127.0.0.1:38367 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:5544]
2012-04-04 17:19:34,414 DEBUG [main] ClientApp - c:false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is calling `clientBootstrap.releaseExternalResources();`.

According to the [documentation](http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap.html#releaseExternalResources%28%29) ... this method simply delegates the call to ChannelFactory.releaseExternalResources().

Comment: Thanks, seems that was a problem.